# PLSQL : value from xpath has some characters on front

Tags: xml, plsql

In PLSQL, I open an xml file and read some nodes with DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.selectNodes to use some xpath expressions.

Everything is fine but for one kind of node only, the value I get (is the good one) has some characters in front of the string. I thought it was some spaces but not.

When I insert the value in the table the characters are still there and there is like an offset I can get rid off.

Do you know what it could be ? how to discover what it could be ? how to get rid of it ?

Note : as those characters are not spaces, trim does not work.

Note2 : the xml seems to be normal

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for an in-database solution the SQL `dump()` function will show you the ASCII values of each character in a string.

```
SQL> select dump('WHAT IS THIS?') from dual
  2  /

DUMP('WHATISTHIS?')
-----------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=13: 87,72,65,84,32,73,83,32,84,72,73,83,63

SQL>
```

As for getting rid of it, you could use `translate()`:

```
SQL> with cte as (select chr(11) || chr(23) || 'WHAT IS THIS?' || chr(23) as str from dual)
  2  select str
  3        , dump(str) as dump_str
  4        , translate(str, 'z'||chr(11)||chr(23), 'z') as cleaned_str
  5  from cte
  6  /

STR              DUMP_STR
---------------- -------------------------------------------------------------
CLEANED_STR
-------------

WHAT IS THIS?
               Typ=1 Len=16: 11,23,87,72,65,84,32,73,83,32,84,72,73,83,63,23
WHAT IS THIS?


SQL>
```

Hmmm. StackOverflow has suppressed the non-printing characters in the SQL output, so it's a little hard to see what's happening without actually running it.